# Twitter authentication without using pin

Tags: windows-phone-7, authentication, twitter

I'm trying to authenticate user accounts in Windows Phone. I found this C# library for the job (tweetsharp).

Their example is pretty clear but they use a pin code to authenticate the user.

```cs
using TweetSharp;

// Pass your credentials to the service
TwitterService service = new TwitterService("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");

// Step 1 - Retrieve an OAuth Request Token
OAuthRequestToken requestToken = service.GetRequestToken();

// Step 2 - Redirect to the OAuth Authorization URL
Uri uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
Process.Start(uri.ToString());

// Step 3 - Exchange the Request Token for an Access Token
string verifier = "123456"; // <-- This is input into your application by your user
OAuthAccessToken access = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

// Step 4 - User authenticates using the Access Token
service.AuthenticateWith(access.Token, access.TokenSecret);
IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> mentions = service.ListTweetsMentioningMe();
```

I was wondering if it's possible to do this without the pincode? I've tried apps that don't ask for the code. Does this mean that tweetsharp is outdated?

Any idea if I can still do the authentication with tweetsharp without using the pin part? Or are there any alternative SDK's out there for windows phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) page there is also mentioned [`xAuth`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth):

> If you are building a mobile application and want to benefit from a
>   seamless authentication experience with no additional steps for the
>   user, you need to enroll your application in Twitter's xAuth support.
>   You must complete this step in order for xAuth to function correctly.

```
using TweetSharp;

// OAuth Access Token Exchange
TwitterService service = new TwitterService("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
OAuthAccessToken access = service.GetAccessTokenWithXAuth("username", "password");
```

Responing to your comment, another option would be using companion web application opened in WebBrowser control in your mobile application, see https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp#authenticating-a-browser-application

Comment: xAuth doesn't offer acces to the user inbox though. And you also have to send a request to be able to use it.

Comment: I updated my answer. Also please see this interesting post about xAuth: http://yourhead.tumblr.com/post/428643811/five-things-you-didnt-know-about-xauth

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Tweetsharp, you can also make use of [Hammock](http://nuget.org/packages/Hammock) library to access Twitter API. Here is a [blog](http://sudheerkovalam.wordpress.com/2010/08/28/a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-part-1/) which explains how to implement OAuth for twitter using Hammock.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: That example also still uses a PIN code which I think isn't used by Twitter anymore. I also tried out the sample code and it doesn't work.

Comment: You are confused between [PIN-based oauth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization) and [Normal Oauth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter) . And the pin which you are assuming in the above blog example is "oauth_verifier" pin. If you have problems with the above post sample code, tell me what problems you are facing?

Comment: I was actually trying the source to which he links in the second part of his tutorial (https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5e51a69c0b38399a&sc=documents&id=5E51A69C0B38399A%21317). When I enter my login details in the twitter webpage I get a popup with "KeyNotFoundException" once I click on authorize. Very vague, but that's all it says..