# How to post a single tweet in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, twitter, windows-phone-7.1, tweets

I am trying to post a single tweet in my Windows phone application to any twitter account. I don't want to complicate my code using external libs or APIs. If they are unavoidable, I will include. I don't need to read any tweets or need to persist my connection. Its simple, The user supplies a username, password and a tweet message and hits tweet.

The famous temple run in iPhone has exactly what I need (screenshot below).

Please guide me in C#

[image]

Comment: have a search/read on twitter oauth authorization and the Twitter API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible via [XAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth). The technique is not straight forward though, your request will have to go through the Twitter API team and once they approve they will give the xAuth Access. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071817/twitter-authentication-without-using-pin) other SOF answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to integrate it like in you screenshot I think you need to communicate with the API yourself.

But there is the `ShareStatusTask` in the `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks` namespace.

With that users can share your status to the social media they configured.

Also check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394027(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: sharestatustask would not work since i need to have the user have the twitter account already pre configured. And there is no way to check whether the user has configured his/her twitter account in his mobile.. That is why i gave up that route.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

- use the built-in `ShareStatusTask`
- roll your own system.

The advantage of `ShareStatusTask` is that it is simple to implement and maintain.

For the user it is also a good solution as it will allow him to post the status on the social network of its choice and it avoids forcing him to authenticate again.

If you want to roll your own system, you'll have to deal with different problems:

- user authentication (OAuth)
- maintenance (sometimes Twitter like to change the way 3rd party apps
  interact with them...)

[Here is a tutorial that explains how to implement Twitter in a Windows Phone app](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/building-twitter-client).

Also [Tweetsharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) is a nice Twitter lib you can use

Comment: ShareStatusTask already went through. Does not fit my specific needs. I am just wondering how the Temple Run game implements without having to do go through OAuth. Tweetsharp also goes through OAuth which i don't want to do .

Comment: Are you sure it still works? I think that Twitter basic auth has been removed. See http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq

Comment: yes, the above one works smoothly and it never had any inbuilt twitter auth redirection

Comment: It would be interesting to see how they do that.  Maybe the authentication is made on the server side but that means that they send the user password to their servers (not very secure...)

Comment: yeah.. suddenly i am curious to see what is going on with that.. will let you know once i find something.. thank you for your replies..

Comment: one interesting link i stumbled upon https://www.odesk.com/o/jobs/job/Twitter-implementation-for-iphone-app_~~c592f3e921dc2a7a/

Comment: Although I could not get an answer what i intended, i get to research a lot of stuff and went into correct direction, hence marking this as the answer.